# CSS modules importing doesn't work despite the righ compilation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I've got a problem with importing css modules to react component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../App.css'

const Button = () => (
    ... className={styles.button}...
)

export default Button;
```

There is no compilation error and stuff like that. Everything seems to by right, but when I run server button looks by default as with no css.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use
Module css must have name `App.module.css`

Then import

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './App.module.css';
```

And use `className={styles.button}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably in your webpack config - please share

In the [css-loader options](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#options), ensure the modules option is set to true